# Force redirect admin to admin dashboard after login WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Am using the snippet below to create separate login and register pages for WooCommerce, however this snippet has overridden my default wp-dmin page so when I want to login via ***example.com/wp-admin***, it redirects to my login page I created ***example.com/login*** then ***after login it redirects to example.com/my-account.***

I need help modifying the login shortcode to redirect users with admin role to admin dashboard after login and users with customer role to my-account dashboard.

**REGISTER PAGE SHORTCODE**

```
/**
 * @snippet       WooCommerce User Login Shortcode
 */
   
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_registration_form' );
    
function bbloomer_separate_registration_form() {
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
   ob_start();
 
   // NOTE: THE FOLLOWING <FORM></FORM> IS COPIED FROM woocommerce\templates\myaccount\form-login.php
   // IF WOOCOMMERCE RELEASES AN UPDATE TO THAT TEMPLATE, YOU MUST CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
 
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
 
   ?>
      <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
         </p>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>
 
         <?php else : ?>
 
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
         </p>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
 
      </form>
 
   <?php
     
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**LOGIN PAGE SHORTCODE**

```
/**
 * @snippet       WooCommerce User Login Shortcode
*/
 
add_shortcode( 'wc_login_form', 'bbloomer_separate' );
  
function bbloomer_separate() {
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   ob_start();
    woocommerce_login_form( array( 'redirect' => 'https://example.com/my-account/' ) );
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Tutorial author here :) Is woocommerce_login_form( array( 'redirect' => 'https://example.com/my-account/' ) ); working the way you want already, and just need an additional rule for admins?

Comment: Yes, its working perfect but admins also get redirected to the my account page so i need an additional rule to redirect admins to admin dashboard. Thank you in advance

Comment: Perfect, posting the solution below shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "conditional logic" to execute a certain function when a given criteria is met.

First of all, I recommend you remove the redirect bit here:

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_login_form', 'bbloomer_separate' );
  
function bbloomer_separate() {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;
    ob_start();
    woocommerce_login_form();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Then, take a look at this other tutorial [WooCommerce: Login Redirect by User Role @ My Account](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-redirect-customer-to-url-upon-login/) and add this to your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'bbloomer_customer_login_redirect', 9999, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_customer_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {        
    if ( wc_user_has_role( $user, 'administrator' ) ) {
        $redirect = '/wp-admin';
    } 
    return $redirect;
}
```